# scaling navigation from vertical center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to scale my navigation (Bootstrap framework) from the vertical center. It scales once 'stuck' to the top of the window. It works fine when it scales down, but scales from the left side when scaled up.

HTML - sticks navigation to top when scrolled to

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var s = $("#attach");
  var pos = s.position();                    
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
        s.addClass("stick");
    } else {
        s.removeClass("stick"); 
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

HTML - navigation snippet

```
<div id="attach-wrap">
        <div id="attach">
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <?php /* Primary navigation */
                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'menu' => 'top_menu',
                    'depth' => 2,
                    'container' => false,
                    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
                    //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
                    'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                    );
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#attach-wrap { height: 50px; }

#attach { 
 height: 50px;
 width: 60%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border-top: 1px solid #000;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 -webkit-transition: height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease;
 -moz-transition: height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease;
 -ms-transition: height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease;
 -o-transition: height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease;
 transition: height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease; 
}

#attach.stick { 
 height: 80px; 
 width: 100%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 background-color: rgba(250,250,250,1);
}

#attach.stick .nav>li>a {
 line-height: 80px; 
}

.stick {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 100;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0; left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please make a snippet or a jsfiddle or something similar.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work but here is what i have https://jsfiddle.net/tLkrf7xq/3/